# Compile Python app with multiple interpreters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a rather big app that need to be installed in a local server.Some of the pc's have windows XP and some other newer version so i need to use 2 interpreters (i want python 3.4 and python 3.6).Sadly i need to use python >3.5 for some of my programm features.It is possible to compile 2 python interpeters in one app and use   them as required?

Comment: The question isn't very clear. Many people have multiple versions of Python on their machines, so of course it is possible. Whether it is a good idea to do it in a single executable is a different question. That would be a very large file.

Comment: So i suppose i should use different versions